# How do I make vim recognize multi-line python comments?

Tags: python, vim, comments

When you use the operator """ code """ to comment out multiple lines in python, vim does not grey out the code. Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: `"""..."""` are not actually multiline comments. They are just strings.

Comment: I see, however, as a string, its not identifying it as one block with the same color; can I make this happen?

Comment: The surrounding `"""` and the surrounded text have the same color by default. Show us some sample code, show us your `vimrc`, and tell us as much as possible about your setup.